# GuzzleHttp throws ConnectExpection cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: <localhostname>

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, laradock

I know there's so many questions about this out there, but I can't seem to find the answer for my own.

I have a `LoginController` with `authenticate()` method which handle login process.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://myapp.test'
        ]);

        $response = $http->post('oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' => '_hashed-secret_',
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'scope' => ''
            ]
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }
}
```

I got `cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: myapp.test (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`.I've rebooted my server, and nothing. I've rebuild all containers (currently using `laradock`), and nothing.

The strange thing is, it only appears on the first attempt login. So, when the client attempt to login, there comes the `error`, but when the client resend the form data (`F5`), it disappears, and the client redirected to the homepage which indicates that the client is logged in.

I also reconfigured my `.env` and other configurations that include `hostname` (previously `localhost`, changed to `myapp.test`) but can't fix the `error`.

Any kind of helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ping myapp.test? Changing hostname to a domain name is not a good idea. Use the hosts file, e.g. add a line `1.2.3.4 myapp.test`

Comment: @marekful yes i can ping myapp.test, and also had add that line to my hosts file, but not work. See my answer, that's what i need, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I already figured it out. Adding some configuration on `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
### PHP-FPM Container #######################################
...
extra_hosts:
  - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
  - "myapp.test:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
networks:
  - frontend
  - backend
  - webserver_network
...
### NGINX Server Container ##################################
networks:
  #- frontend
  #- backend
  webserver_network:
    ipv4_address: ${WEBSERVER_IP}
  frontend:
  backend:
...
### Networks Setup ############################################
webserver_network:
  driver: "bridge"
  config:
    - subnet: "${WEBSERVER_SUBNET}"
      gateway: "${WEBSERVER_GATEWAY}"
```

Then, rebuild `php-fpm` container. And got it works. Thanks.

Comment: Where did u find the `docker-compose.yml?`